# How can I set cron for some specific php file

Tags: magento-cron, magento-1.9.3.4

I created `test.php` file in the `root` folder. I want to this file run automatically in every 2 minutes. I know this is done using `cron`. but I don't know how to set up `cron`. so can any one give me example or explain in detail how can I set `cron` job for this file.I create this file in my local `magento` setup.

Thanks in Advance. `Magento version:1.9.3.4`.

Comment: do you have a cpanel or plesk on server or ssh access?

Comment: https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230244168-Setting-up-cron-jobs-with-cPanel- Try this.

Comment: cron job not work in local setup?